# How to read CSS properties of elements dynamically loaded with external script on Android browser?

Tags: android, html, css

I have a webpage that loads an reCaptcha element that is supposed to be subsequently modified by css:

```
#recaptcha_widget_div {
    margin: 0 -20px !important;
    background: cyan;
}
```

It works on Google Chrome, but has absolutely no effect when viewed on Android browser. I am not sure what is the problem. Is there a way to look at the css properties of the element on Android?

I know there is an `about:debug`, but not sure how I can put it to use.

Comment: you can remotely debug using an android device via USB https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Ghostlab](http://vanamco.com/ghostlab/), which (among other things) sets up a proxy server with Weinre (WEbkit Inspect REmote), that you then connect to using any browser, and it allows you to debug using the Webkit inspector. Very handy, but Mac only so far, so if you're on Windows or Linux, have a look at this [article by Peter Gasston on setting Weinre up manually](http://www.broken-links.com/2013/06/28/remote-debugging-with-weinre/).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I managed to troubleshoot the problem to a missing bracket that is tolerated by Chrome but not Android.